# Firefox does not expand div vertically

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have implemented a table and inside of the table are 's containing background-images. 
The images are displayed correct in Safari, Chrome and Opera. 
But just Firefox does not display anything in the table cells.

I have found out that for a reason that I do not know Firefox does not expand my divs using fix sizes:

```
height: 100px; width: 100px;
```

I figured out that Firefox displays the width correctly when I use

```
height: 50px; width: -moz-available;
```

But the height still does not work and I cannot find any solution for my problem...

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="section" id="section1">

        <table class="tableReferences">
            <tr class="row1">
                <td>
                    <table class="tableRow1">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cell1">
                                <div class="referencesPic" style="height: 50px; width: -moz-available; background-image:url(../img/officePic.jpg);background-size: cover; background-position:center center;"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cell2">

                               <div class="container">
                                <div class="demo num1">

                                <table class="hoverContent">

                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="hoverContent">
                                                Backgroundtext
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>

                                </div>

                                <div class="effects clearfix num2 effect-1">
                                <div class="img invisibleAnimationContainer"> 
                                <img src="../img/background.png" alt="" >
                                    <div class="overlay expand"> 

                                    <table class="hoverContent">

                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="hoverContent">
                                                hallo meine Freunde
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            </td>
                            <td class="cell3">

                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="demo num1" style="height: 50px; width: -moz-available; background-image:url(../img/referencesPic.jpg);background-size: cover; background-position:center center;"></div>

                                <div class="effects clearfix num2 effect-1">
                                <div class="img invisibleAnimationContainer"> 
                                <img src="../img/background.png" alt="" >
                                    <div class="overlay expand"> 

                                    <table class="hoverContent">

                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="hoverContent">
                                                Foregroundtext
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

      </div>


      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS file I use just implements that each part of the table
expands to its parent container.

The important CSS parts where my problem is caused for sure are implemented directly inside of the HTML file. 
I have also shortened the HTML code to just one row.

This is how the website looks correctly in Chrome:

[image: This is how the website looks correctly in Chrome]

The Website displayed completely wrong in Firefox:

[image: The Website displayed completely wrong in Firefox]

And in Firefox using

```
 height: 50px; width: -moz-available;
```

[image]

---

okay, now I have tried to do the stuff just with divs positioned next to each other. 
My problem is now, that I am not able to position the divs in one row horizontally. I have tried many examples that I have found on the internet.

I cannot find out why the divs in the row do not place themselves horizontally...

My Table:

```
<div class="referencesContainer">
            <div class="row row1">
                <div id="left">Left Side Menu</div>
                <div id="middle">Random Content</div>
                <div id="right">Right Side Menu</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row row2">
            </div>

            <div class="row row3">
            </div>
        </div>
```

see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7q3pn6w/)

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question. See above

Comment: Please add full links to the JavaScript and CSS files. Local references are useless to us. In addition to that, there is a lot of code there for us to scour through. Please try and reduce this as much as possible, and try to create a working Snippet in the question or link to a JSFiddle.

Comment: I have updated my question again. A JSFiddle would not help because my problem can just be recreated inside of Firefox.

Comment: Rule number one; do I still use tables? Yes? Remove tables and please try again. Tables are meant for tabular data. Not for anything else. Definitely not for containing background images.

Comment: JSFiddle works in FireFox.  I don't see the problem.  If you post a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem in FireFox, we can open the JSFiddle with FireFox and see for ourselves.  Same with Stack Snippets (runnable code you can embed right in your question).

Comment: Okay. I See. I thought always that Jsfiddle has its own interpreter....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using display:flex; and flex-wrap: wrap; on your .row (in CSS), then set your left, right and inner div to a % width so that they make up a 100% in total?